# How to draw a straight perpendicular line between 2 other parallel lines?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-graphics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZi76.png)
I need to draw the first line using location of finger.
Later I need to draw the second parallel line using location of finger.
I have already done it. 
And the main task is to draw the third perpendicular line between those parallel lines.
How can I draw the third line?

Comment: So what's the question other than making some statements?

Comment: Is this a question about (Swift) programming or about geometry/mathematics?

Comment: @ElTomato How to draw a perpendicular line between parallel lines?

Comment: @MartinR about Swift programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 parallel lines and wish to draw perpendicular line between them you will need 1 extra point. Assume that this point is at the middle of first line (call it `C`).

Also assume we have the following:

```
L1 // Represents the first line
L2 // Represents the second line
L1.start // Represents the line start point CGPoint
L1.end // Represents the line end point CGPoint
```

Now you wish to draw a perpendicular line to first line `L1` and to do so you will need to get its `normal` which is pretty simple in 2D. First get the line direction by subtracting start and end point of a given line `direction = CGPoint(x: L1.end.x-L1.start.x, y: L1.end.y-L1.start.y)`. Now to get the normal we simply need to invert coordinates and divide them by direction length:

```
let length = sqrt(direction.x*direction.x + direction.y*direction.y)
let normal = CGPoint(x: -direction.y/length, y: direction.x/length) // Yes, normal is (-D.y, D.x)
```

So as said the start point is `C` now we only need to find the end point on the other line which is `C + normal*distanceBetweenLines`. So we need the distance between the two lines which should be best received through dot product...

First we need a vector between any pair of points from the two lines (one point on first line and the other one on the second line). So let's take

`let between = CGPoint(x: L1.start.x-L2.start.x, y: L1.start.y-L2.start.y)`

Now we need to project this line to normal with dot product to get the length of the projection which is the length between the two lines

`let distanceBetweenLines = between.x*normal.x + between.y*normal.y`.

So now we have all the points to draw perpendicular line between 2 given lines assuming the lines are parallel:

```
L3.start = C
L3.end = CGPoint(x: C.x + normal.x*distanceBetweenLines, y: C.y + normal.y*distanceBetweenLines)
```